# difference between (new class())->someMethod() and (new Class)->someMethod()

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying find a difference between
`(new class())->someMethod()` and `(new Class)->someMethod()`.
I tried some code on local looks like both are same,
Please help me here

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new

Answer (score -1):

```php
class Foo {
    function __construct() {
        echo __METHOD__ . "\n";
    }
    function bar() {
        echo __METHOD__ . "\n";
    }
}

(new Foo())->bar();
(new Foo)->bar();

/**output
Foo::__construct
Foo::bar
Foo::__construct
Foo::bar

*/
```

in fact, no different but have one small difference,

**__contruct is called on both**

```php
(new class())->someMethod() //does call __construct with parameter when get instance

(new class)->someMethod() // no need call  __construct when get instance
```

**You have to use it in the `(new class())->foo()` way according to psr standards**

for example

```php
class User
{
    
    private string $name;
    
    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name=$name;
    }
}
//in tsis scenarion you have use (new User('john'));
```

**If you do not need the _construct parameters, you can use it as `(new User)->foo().`**

```
class User
{

}
//class doesnt want _construct parameters
```

**It must be called as `(new User())`. For example, this `__construct` method expects a parameter although the parameter does not appear.**

```php
class User{

    public function __construct()
    {

        print_r(func_get_args());
    }
}


(new User(1,'ff'));
```

Comment: Don't spread wrong information :( http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52cece400fb3be5d8d2297bbefa83da9bec36b4f

Comment: As (new class)->someMethod() this will create new instance ,  then How can new instance be created without calling construct?

Comment: "If there are no arguments to be passed to the class's constructor, parentheses after the class name may be omitted. " ... that is the only difference, its not a functional difference

Comment: I'd suggest, to give a clear answer to the question, you erase what you have currently and (with permission) replace it with the comment of @lagbox...